# The display of my char array is short the last few characters. C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I am wondering why the display of the char array is short few characters. However, when I use length+2, all characters are displayed. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Your help will be appreciated. I am using Dev-C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>


using namespace std;

char *Appendstring(char *a, char *b, char *c, char *d, char *e)  // will append b to the end of a
{
// char *buffer = new char[strlen(a)+strlen(b)+1];

 static char buffer[90];

    char *p=buffer;
    while(*p++=*a++); // Copy a into buffer
    while(*p++=*b++); // Copy b into buffer right after a
    while(*p++=*c++);  // Copy c into buffer right after b
    while(*p++=*d++);  // Copy d into buffer right after c
    while(*p++=*e++);  // Copy e into buffer right after d
    *p=0; // Null-terminate the string
    return buffer;  
}

int main ()
{
    char *new_string;
    int length;
    char *str="Because";
    char *add="it has been";
    char *addstr1="very warm";
    char *addstr2="lately";
    char *addstr3="Summer is coming!";


    length=strlen(str)+strlen(add)+strlen(addstr1)+strlen(addstr2)+strlen(addstr3)+1;  //total length of the new string

    new_string=Appendstring(str, add, addstr1, addstr2, addstr3);
    for (int i=0; i<=length+2; i++)  //Why do I need to do length+2 to have all characters displayed???
  cout<<new_string[i];

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your string copying code is wrong. It copies the null bytes at the end of the strings too.

Try this

```
while (*a) // Copy a into buffer
    *p++ = *a++;
while (*b) // Copy b into buffer
    *p++ = *b++;
```

etc.

Comment: +1. And problems like this are exactly why one should use `std::string` in C++ instead of char arrays.

Comment: this is the output after trying your suggestion:
"Becauseit has beenvery warmlatelySummer is coming!" whereas the output of my current clode is: ""Because it has been very warm lately Summer is comi".

Comment: @Angew, the requirement for the assignment is to use dynamic char array, and to append them. I am not allowed to use std::string for this assignment.

Comment: @T4000 So after trying my suggestion the output is correct? Or is there still a problem?

Comment: @john, this is the output after trying your suggestion: "Becauseit has beenvery warmlatelySummer is coming!" the whole string is printed out,except there are no spaces where it should have.

Comment: @T4000 But there are no spaces in your input strings either!!! The 'spaces' you were seeing were the null characters you were wrongly copying. If you want spaces change `"Because"` to `"Because "`, `"it has been"` to `"it has been "` etc. Appending strings shouldn't automatically add spaces, if you want spaces you have to put them there yourself.

Comment: @john,Is there anyway we can append the char arrays without adding that extra space at the end of each string? Because if I have let say 100 char arrays, should I go over each string and add the extra space at the end of each one of them? I am just trying to find a more efficient way to append without adding manually the space.

Comment: You'd have to change your code, so it adds the spaces between the strings. You'd also have to change your length calculation to account for the extra spaces. It's perfectly possible, you just have to write the code to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually printing out 4 non-printable characters in your for loop.

The total number of printable characters in your strings is 50. Your length variable is 51 because you add 1 to it. Then the for loop is from 0 to 51+2, which will print out a total of 54 characters.

But, since your Appendstring function is incorrectly embedding the null bytes as John describes, you have 4 null characters in the string. When you stream a null character to cout, it is non-printable and nothing is displayed.

Once you change the Appendstring function as John describes, then you will not need to add 1 to length and the for loop should be

```
for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
```